# Use fake data for integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, liquibase

I use Liquibase tool with Spring Boot for database management.
Liquibase allows to manage fake data for development. This data is then inserted when the server is switched on in development mode.
I would like to use the same data but for my tests.

For the moment I use the following annotation:

```java
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "spring.liquibase.drop-first=true",
    "spring.liquibase.contexts=test, faker"
})
```

This solution works if I run the tests individually, but does not work anymore when I run them successively `mvn verify`.
Indeed, once inserted in the database, these are not deleted at the end of the tests of a class and are kept for all other tests.

Would you know how to solve this problem?
Would you have another solution to use this fake data?

Comment: Have you tried `Lifecycle.PER_METHOD` (which is the default)?

Comment: it doesn't look any better